# Python inst/klass instead of self?

Tags: python, class, naming-conventions, instance

Sometimes self can denote the instance of the class and sometimes the class itself. So why don't we use `inst` and `klass` instead of `self`? Wouldn't that make things easier?

**How things are now**

```
class A:
  @classmethod
  def do(self): # self refers to class
    ..

class B:
  def do(self): # self refers to instance of class
    ..
```

**How I think they should be**

```
class A:
  @classmethod
  def do(klass): # no ambiguity
    ..

class B:
  def do(inst): # no ambiguity
    ..
```

So how come we don't program like this when in the [zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) it is stated that *explicit is better than implicit*? Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: I think self is pretty explicit.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham how can it be explicit when it refers to two different things in different situations?

Comment: @Piyhkos,  I mean in relation to  the instance, you use `cls` with a classmethod

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Class method support was added much later to Python, and the convention to use `self` for instances had already been established. Keeping that convention stable has more value than to switch to a longer name like `instance`.

The convention for class methods is to use the name `cls`:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def do(cls):
```

In other words, the conventions are *already there* to distinguish between a class object and the instance; never use `self` for class methods.

Also see [PEP 8 - *Function and method arguments*](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments):

> Always use `self` for the first argument to instance methods.
>
> Always use `cls` for the first argument to class methods.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be better to use "cls":

```
class A:
  @classmethod
  def do(cls): # cls refers to class
    ..

class B:
  def do(self): # self refers to instance of class
    ..
```

It's requirement of PEP8:

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments

Comment: the OP is also asking why `self` is not something like `inst`

Comment: I think difference between cls and self is quite clear: cls means class, and self means instance, it's common approach to naming in python.

Comment: I am not asking the OP is

Answer (score 3):

I think the point is that conventially you don't use `self` for methods wrapped with `@classmethod`. (You could write `kls`, `cls`, etc.)

There is ultimately nothing stopping you from writing `inst` instead of `self` if you so desire. So your second example would work fine and is actually the expected way to handle it (in terms of distinguishing an instance vs a class). However, you should definitely use `self` when dealing with instances. It's a Python convention and breaking it is strongly discouraged.

#### PEP8

Seeing as others have mentioned it, it's true PEP8 does say to use both `self` and `cls` in the case of instance and class methods, respectively. The only thing I'd add to this is that while there isn't any sensible reason to break this rule, changing `self` is significantly worse (from a semantic POV) because of its strong use inside of 99.999% of Python code. Its use is so *universal* that many (if not most) beginners assume it's a keyword and are confused by the idea that one can *change self to anything*.

This strong relationship to code and convention is not so apparent with class methods IMO. Of course I would urge anyone to follow PEP8 as much as possible, but if you felt inclined to  use `kls` instead of `cls`, I feel that you'd be committing a lesser evil than if you changed `self`. However, whichever name you go with *should* remain consistent throughout your program.